# Full Adder boolean Algebra simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have an expression here from the [Full Adder circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29#Full_adder), used for binary addition. One equation used to make it work, is this one:

$$C = xy + xz + yz \tag{1}$$

Now, the book transforms this equation into this:
$$C = z(x'y + xy') + xy \tag{2}$$

In the immediate step, the do this:
$$C = z(x \oplus y) + xy \tag{3}$$

Now, my question is how does the second equation come from the first one?

Comment: What is your definition of the exclusive-or ($x \oplus y$)?

Comment: @Adriano: The standard definition : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table

Comment: Then, by definition, we can replace ($x \oplus y$) with $(x'y + xy')$.

Comment: @Adriano: Yes, ofcourse, but if you take a look at the question, How do you arrive from the first equation to the third one? This was my fault, I will replace 2nd with the 3rd. My mistake, many apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align*}
C & = xy + xz + yz\\
& = xy + x(y + y')z + (x + x')yz \\
& = xy + xyz + xy'z + xyz + x'yz \\
& = xy(1 + z + z) + (xy' + x'y)z \\
& = xy + (xy' + x'y)z \\
& = xy + (x \oplus y)z
\end{align*}

Comment: On line 4, how do you get $xy(1+z+z)$ for the last term, because $xyz != xy'z$

Comment: @Games The third and fourth terms ($xy'z$ and $xyz$) were swapped before the $xy$ and $z$ were factored out.

Comment: @Adriano: Yes, I get it now. Sorry to be so dumb. Thanks to the both of you for your help. Hope one day, I can answer questions on the site, like you guys.